# Convert a SQL query to a Hibernate Criteria expression

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria, restriction

I'm having trouble converting this expression to a Criteria expression:

```
SELECT profile_profiles.profile_sup_id 
  FROM profil
  INNER JOIN profile_profiles ON profile_profiles.profile_id = profil.id 
        AND profil.id = 4
```

Can anyone help?

i have one table 'Profil' Many to Many and refelxive

Profil 1 --- profile_profiles --- Profil 2

```
public class Profil implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String libelle;
    private Set<Profil> profiles = new HashSet<Profil>(0);
...
}
```

hbm

```
<set name="profiles" table="profile_profiles" cascade="all">
            <key column="profile_id" />
            <many-to-many column="profile_sup_id" class="com.steriamedshore.proboard.model.referentiel.Profil" />
        </set>
```

Comment: Is it a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship? Do you have an association set up in your hibernate configuration between those two classes? If you don't I do not believe what you want is possible.

Comment: Well in that case you can refer to JB Nizet's answer, I wanted to write exactly the same thing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Profil.class, "profil");
c.createAlias("profil.profiles", "supProfil");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("profil.id", 4);
c.setProjection(Projections.property("supProfil.id"));
```

The above should, AFAIK, make an additional join from the join table to the profile table, but it should return the same thing as your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much @JB Nizet

I did actually find the solution yesterday :

```
hibernateCriteria.createCriteria("profil").createAlias("profiles", "ps").add( Restrictions.eq("ps.id",superieurCriteria.getProfilId()) ) ;
```

peace.